# Massive delays in simple script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, delay

This script loops to open the temp.rtf file. Script pauses automatically until current file instance is closed. I get anywhere from **0 to 30 seconds delay before it opens a new window**. I also noticed it when using cmd with subprocess.run in python. Can someone explain what is happening? This completely breaks python..

```
import sys, subprocess

def redir(tag):
    if str(tag)=='journal':
        subprocess.run("temp.rtf", shell=True)

while __name__=="__main__":
    redir('journal')
```

Argument for redir (last line) is actually argv but this should work the same.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        redir('journal')
```

^gives same delay

*Using windows 10, task manager says 7% CPU max, nothing else.

Entering code into cmd gives no delay in opening the file but the same major delay is apparent in the cmd windows not closing for random amounts of time.

Comment: Why are you using `while __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: I thought that made it a infinite loop instead of a single use script - if statement doesnt change anything noticeable

Comment: Drop the `while True:` line

Comment: This is Windows, I'm guessing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes... Considering switching to linux but I need to have it working on Windows..

Comment: Honestly, I expect it's your virus scanner or some similar piece of unrelated infrastructure on Windows injecting the delay.

Answer (score 0):

From your shell, type in the command to open the same file.
Run this simple test 6 times: which are the startup delay of every run?

You don't specify nor the operating system neither the application and the system load (other runnimg processes, cpu load, memory load).

---

The last comment by the author is significant:

> Cmd.exe /C command- line

Every time a new  command processor is started, it executes, before the command-line, other programs (auto startup entries).

You can use the switch /D before /C

> /D     Ignore registry AutoRun commands

Ref.
https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

To see the autoruns entries you can use Autoruns from sysinternals:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

---

If this switch doesn't work, I suggest you to see the other free tools at sysinternals, they can help you to find suspects and bottlenecks.

For example, process explorer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: Using windows 10, task manager says 7% CPU max, nothing else.

Entering code into cmd gives no delay in opening the file but the same major delay is apparent in the cmd windows not closing for random amounts of time. Running the code the first time (in python) always opens directly and no delay in closing of cmd window

Comment: Sorry I don't understand *but the same major delay is apparent in the cmd windows* If the program, at random, is slow ... it will manifest the same problems running from python.

Comment: Dumb suggestion: at the dos prompt, change the current directory where the program is installed and run it. Any difference?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaking code. Running: || subprocess.run('''start cmd /c "python -c "import func; func.redir('journal')""''', shell=True) || gives me the same delays in closing the cmd windows that pop up to open the file (which are selfclosing because of the use of /c )

Comment: Perhaps your last comment is the right hint. I update my answer.

Comment: I tried changing directories. Switching drives also doesn't work